# How do I list the running nodes with geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, nodes

Is there a way to list the all nodes on my computer with [`geth` command line](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options), and maybe even see some status for them?

(I'm new to go-ethereum, apologies if this is a noob question, but I cannot quite find the answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't have any `geth` nodes running on your machine unless you have explicitly started them. In order to run multiple full nodes, you would need to have explicitly chosen different ports for each when creating them, and your machine would need to have hundreds of GB of storage in order to accommodate for them.

---

If you *do* have many running, then there are a few ways to go about knowing if they are running or seeing their status.

To know if they are running, you can simply run `ps aux | grep geth` to see how many processes with the word `geth` in them are running.

If you want to know that output of the `geth` instance (and you don't have them all running in various terminal sessions), you would have to log the output to a file and read the file.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now. So there is no built in geth command to give you some dashboard overview, but instead I have to check it's process as you suggested.